# How can I use multipleselect with angular 4?

Tags: angular, multiple-select

I want to use multiple select in my angular 4 project, but it doesnt work. I followed the installation guide from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-multiselect-dropdown

(install multiple select via npm, include the component in my module, add the html in my template)

But I get following error:

> Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'angular2 
>       multiselect'.
>       1. If 'angular2-multiselect' is an Angular component and it has 'data' 
>       input, then verify that it is part of this module.

Can you please help me?

Comment: added "AngularMultiSelectModule"  into module?

Comment: I will suggest you with [**ng2-select**](https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/)

Comment: I put the AngularMultiSelectModule in the wrong module. Apperently, I cant use this module in my "SharedModule"

Comment: are you able to do this now?

Answer (score 1):

Why not consider using Angular Material?

Built by Angular/Google team they have many UI components for Angular.

They have a dropdown allowing multi select.(Scroll Down till you see " Multiple selection ")

https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Comment: Angular Material does not support IE (9-11).

Comment: There was no mention in the question of needing support for that.